# Is there a way to customly define a color in the levelplot function in the lattice package when already using a col.region?

Tags: r, heatmap, lattice, levelplot

im using the levelplot function of the lattice-package to display the results in a simulation study of detecting serial independance in simulated AR-time series under different alternatives. As a color sheme im using the magma colors of the viridis-package and now im trying to highlight those alternatives, where the rejection-rate is lower than 0.05 in an additional color to increase the visiability of those alternatives.
Is there anyway to specify this in the levelplot function?

Heres a try on a minimal example:

```
library(lattice) 
library(viridis)


Grid=expand.grid(mean=seq(0,0.5,by=0.01),rho=seq(0,0.5,by=0.01))

X=seq(1,dim(Grid)[1])
Rej=sapply(X, function(X) sum(Grid[X,]$mean,Grid[X,]$rho))
Grid$Rej=Rej

levelplot(Rej ~ mean*rho, data=Grid ,layers=1,col.regions=magma, at=seq(0,1,by=0.05))
```

Here im looking to have the values below 0.05 in another color than black, because its hard to spot if the alpha-level is met.

Thanks in advance,
Hendrik

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It's easier to help you if you make your question reproducible including data and your code which can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Have a look at https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5 and [mre]

Comment: The information in your comment is probably best included as part of the question: asking a minimal reproducible question is not always easy, but it is worth the effort as it helps one's own understanding of what is going  on and improves your chances of someone being prepared to spend their time helping you out with an answer.

Comment: Ok im trying... thank you!